# UBER - Deleting or Cancelling Booking

Tags: uber-api

I am Searching for finding a "curl" request for cancelling the current booking in UBER,

I have Gone through the following Official [link](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-delete) but still i can't get it done.

The following is the code snippet given

I don't know what that -X means.

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>' \
     -H 'Accept-Language: en_US' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -X DELETE \
     'https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/<REQUEST_ID>'
```

If any one can help me that would be great.

Comment: Have you considered reading the curl docs? Or just comparing its value to, say, the HTTP verbs and thinking about what it might represent?

Comment: I have searched the docs but i cant find what x means, for H i know that its Header

Comment: It seems you didn't look very hard: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-X

Comment: Thanks man, i should have digged in deeper.

Comment: I mean I literally just used "find in page" and typed `-X`

Comment: ok dude. I didn't searched like you did. I scrolled and didn't get and i moved on to another website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deletion of submitted requests, please apply following endpoint

```
DELETE https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/{request_id}
```

Using this call, you will delete specific request identified by {request_id}.
Check the documentation for more info [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-delete).

Comment: Thanks dude. I figured it out. Thanks for the tip